# Polyakov equation in the strings theory

Tags: string-theory, quantum-anomalies

In the equation of Polyakov there wouldn't be in our universe 10 or 11 dimensions but more (26) because it is referred to the bosonic theory. Are there any connections between this equation and the invariance of Lorentz? Can you explain where, also in form of formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways to see that the bosonic string lives in $D=26$. This, by the way, is known as the critical dimension of the theory. I'll give a brief sketch the answer, a more complete one can be found in any textbook, but in particular Polchinski's.

Classically, the Polyakov action has 3 main symmetries. These are: 1) Lorentz invariance of the target space (the $D$-dim. space), 2) diffeomorphism invariance of the worldsheet theory, and 3) worldsheet Weyl invariance.

Quantum mechanically, there is a potential for any of these symmetries to become anomalous (an anomaly is when a symmetry of a classical theory is not a symmetry of the quantized theory). Upon quantization, it is found that these symmetries will be anomalous unless $D=26$. The easiest way to see this is to quantize the open string in light-cone gauge, and find that the photon will be massive unless $D=26$. (A massive photon is inconsistent with Lorentz invariance).

Comment: It is also worth noting that the worldsheet diffeomorphism invariance is a gauge symmetry, so an anomaly would lead to an inconsistent theory.